# limit number os characters in a field, when using p-password component of primeng

Tags: javascript, angular, input, primeng, maxlength

I'm trying to limit the number of characters on an input using primeng 12, the maxlength property doesn't seem to work with this password component, on a normal input works fine but I need the special features like a template of password strength, what can I do?

```
            <p-password  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [pKeyFilter]="blockSpace" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" placeholder="Contraseña" formControlName="password" maxlength='16' [feedback]="false"></p-password>
```

On a regular input the max length prevents typing more than 16 characters but with p-password users cant type infinite characters

Answer (score 0):

Really late answer but as the issue is still there on primeng 13. Here below the solution I have implemented to add the functionality. I'm using a directive. Hope it helps

```
import {
    AfterContentChecked,
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    Input
} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[compPasswordMaxLength]',
})
export class CompPasswordMaxLengthDirective
    implements AfterContentChecked {

    @Input('compPasswordMaxLength') length: number;

    private domElement: HTMLElement;
    
    constructor( private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        // get ref HTML element
        this.domElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    }

    public ngAfterContentChecked(): void {

        const input = this.domElement.getElementsByTagName('input');

        if (input && input.length > 0) {
            (input[0] as HTMLElement).setAttribute('maxlength', this.length.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<p-password formControlName="password" [compPasswordMaxLength]="maxLength_Password">
</p-password>
```